# Каким типом связи связано обстоятельство со сказуемым в предложении?

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания

Каким типом связи связано обстоятельство со сказуемым в предложении:

> Справа видна серебристая лента
> полноводной реки.

Я думаю, что примыкание, правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я думаю, что примыкание, правильно?

ПРАВИЛЬНО.